# Asynchronous Web API Endpoint

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

The following Web API end point is still getting the following error:

> "A second operation started on this context before a previous
>   asynchronous operation completed."

Since I'm using the `.ToListAsync` with the data returned from Entity Framework, I'm assuming the problem is with the `var user` line blocking.

How do I make that part async as well?

```
[Route("Retailers/{search}")]
[HttpGet]
public Task<List<Lookup>> Retailers(string search)
{
    var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    Guid userId = Guid.Parse(user.Id);

    var companies = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Company>().GetAll().Where(c => c.CompanyType == CompanyType.Retail && 
                (c.UserID == null || c.UserID == userId) && c.CompanyName.StartsWith(search)).Take(5)
                .Select(x => new Lookup { Id = x.Id, Name = x.CompanyName }).ToListAsync();

    return companies;
}
```

Comment: The blocking `FindById` is not going to cause this problem. I suspect the problem is somewhere in your unit of work abstraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `async` and the `await` keywords.

1. Add `async` to the method signature.
2. Add `await` to your call to `_unitOfWork.GetRepository...ToListAsync()`

Code:

```
[Route("Retailers/{search}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<List<Lookup>> Retailers(string search)
{
    var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    Guid userId = Guid.Parse(user.Id);

    var companies = await _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Company>().GetAll().Where(c => c.CompanyType == CompanyType.Retail && 
                (c.UserID == null || c.UserID == userId) && c.CompanyName.StartsWith(search)).Take(5)
                .Select(x => new Lookup { Id = x.Id, Name = x.CompanyName }).ToListAsync();

    return companies;
}
```

As a reference here is a good link to asynchronous programming: [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Comment: And why does that work now and not before? The old code simply returns the existing task, the framework should not be able to tell the difference.

Comment: await exists to make it easier to write such functions. Callers cannot tell whether a method is implemented using async or not. When code is compiled this information is lost. But maybe the use of await here has some other effect making this code work. I don't see why it would, though.

Comment: Well, it did.  Works great now.  I'm using this with a TypeAhead control, and I'm able to literally hold the key down.